# Como executar um método na inicialização de TODOS os Controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, controller

Tenho uma classe estática que carrega a linguagem em relação ao *cookie* armazenado ou o URL. Em todo *controller* tenho que inserir uma vez o seguinte método:

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
    LanguageCookieController.Load(); //Método que carrega
    base.Initialize(requestContext);
}
```

Porém aconteceu casos na qual eu esqueci de adicionar essas chamadas e por isso todas as *views* do *controller* X não carregam a linguagem que o usuário está.

Como faço para executar esse `Initialize()` não somente em um *controller*, mas em todos, inclusive os que irão ser adicionados?

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 1):

Herda a classe `Controller` para uma outra sua onde você personaliza do jeito que quiser, neste caso colocando este método, vamos chamar de `AppController`, aí em vez de herdar de `Controller` herda da sua nova classe `AppController`, herança foi feita para isto.

Claro que você pode esquecer de herdar da sua, mas nem todos problemas podem ser resolvidos quando o problema é do programador :)